# Google Analytics API call frequently returns expected data but occasionally the same call returns error 500

Tags: google-analytics

we have been running Google Analytics(GA) API for several accounts .
It works well for all the accounts except for one which occasionally(not always) fails and returns the error 500.

Regarding the account with the problem, the error 500 started to happen since last year(2020/DEC).
The occurrence of this error(500) shows a tendency to happen when the API CALL is made to fetch reports for periods over 3 days (However the chance of this error for periods shorter than 3 days so far has not been zero.)

Regarding the explanation above↑ the problem seems to be in GA side.
May we ask your assistance to check up the situation and help us to solve the problem.
We deeply appreciate all your help and kindness.

Below, As an example I paste the returned response(error 500) for the API call we made in 2021/JULY/8.

Best regards,
Shahin

```
I, [2021-07-09T18:11:44.314945 #13000]  INFO -- : get https://analytics.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?dimensions=ga%3Adate%2Cga%3AadDistributionNetwork%2Cga%3AsourceMedium%2Cga%3AadKeywordMatchType%2Cga%3Akeyword%2Cga%3AadContent%2Cga%3Acampaign&end-date=2021-07-08&ids=ga%3A61390358&max-results=1000&metrics=ga%3Agoal11Completions%2Cga%3Agoal12Completions%2Cga%3Agoal13Completions%2Cga%3Agoal14Completions%2Cga%3Agoal15Completions%2Cga%3Agoal16Completions%2Cga%3Agoal17Completions%2Cga%3Agoal18Completions%2Cga%3Agoal19Completions%2Cga%3Agoal20Completions&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION&start-date=2021-07-04&start-index=2001
D, [2021-07-09T18:11:48.813256 #13000] DEBUG -- request: User-Agent: "analytics/v3 google-api-ruby-client/0.8.6 Linux/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64\n (gzip)"
Accept-Encoding: "gzip"
Content-Type: ""
Authorization: "Bearer ya29.a0ARrdaM9m7nl7eZ40UtyNPMLo-quMyknO5gC6d60ucF2zhN3WgO_YcsHtldGyqpjuTsHUJAFurvcC3cryutiB2U2P_Wf-gM6DtnhkAqEjoPfCKwsWeuz8wrFgXfa7M3QknRcFDFrWO0CNrEKeDG7caf0B1R49Rws"
Cache-Control: "no-store"
D, [2021-07-09T18:11:48.813315 #13000] DEBUG -- request: 
I, [2021-07-09T18:12:48.790970 #13000]  INFO -- Status: 500
D, [2021-07-09T18:12:48.791044 #13000] DEBUG -- response: vary: "Origin, X-Origin, Referer"
content-type: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
date: "Fri, 09 Jul 2021 09:12:48 GMT"
server: "ESF"
cache-control: "private"
x-xss-protection: "0"
x-frame-options: "SAMEORIGIN"
x-content-type-options: "nosniff"
alt-svc: "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\""
connection: "close"
transfer-encoding: "chunked"
D, [2021-07-09T18:12:48.791065 #13000] DEBUG -- response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "There was an internal error.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "There was an internal error.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "internalError"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: 500 errors on google side there is rarely anything you did that caused it.  Try and run the request again the server may just have been overloaded or there is to much data to create the report.

Comment: Hi DaImTo,
thank you very much for your immediate answer. Very kind of you.
Well, what makes it suspicious is that "Why this error(500) always happens to the same specific account and never to the other ones? Despite using the same API with the same conditions(apart from the credentials) for all of them."
I appreciate your answer very much, and continue to see other comments aswell if there is any.

Comment: What time of day is it running, what is the location of the account ?  I would also wonder if there could be something internally wrong with your credentials.